# How do I reinstall the Search/Indexing Feature on Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, search, uninstall

We have trouble with the SearchIndexer on Windows 2012 R2. Microsoft suggests do uninstall the feature and reinstall it.

Where can I do that in Windows Server 2012? Can't find the feature in the feature list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Server Manager`, click on `Add roles and features` click next until you get to `Features` and then uncheck `Windows Search Service` and complete the wizard.
You might be best of sharing the issue you are having as well, is it a performance issue due to this service?

Comment: Also if you are not using this service or don't want to index you can disable the service instead `WSearch`.

Comment: It's de grayed and can't be unchecked (tested with started and stopped service)

Comment: Are you a local admin? You can also try the PowerShell command, but make sure you are running the shell as an administrator `Uninstall-WindowsFeature Search-Service`. This also requires a restart.

Answer (score 1):

KV:  a big thank you for that idea.  It didn't work quite the same for me, but led to solution.

My File Explorer (on a 2012R2) had the 'green bar death.'  The Indexing Option tool was frozen with a message 'waiting to receive indexing status.'  In that frozen state there did not appear to be a way to the'index rebuilding,'

Then I found your post.  Went into Services to stop Windows Search as you suggested.  At this point something strange happened.  There was a message that 'windows search can not be stopped.'  However, at the same time the Indexing  Option tool was awoken out of slumber and I was able to do an 'index rebuild.'

And now file explorer works very well.

Answer (score -1):

I simply stopped the "Windows Search" service on the server (Server 2012 Standard) and it instantly fixed this issue. I have now disabled it.

[image]

Comment: The question was how to fix, not how to disable it. And please stop shouting (writing all caps).